# WiX HeatDirectory task pointing to symlink

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am using the HeatDirectory task in a Wix-Project to fetch some files. I would furthermore like to use a symlink in the HeatDirectory *Directory* parameter to always use the folder the shortcut is pointing to. However, it seems the parameter feels not very comfortable with this symlink, so I tried creating a workaround by copying the files before harvesting them.

```
<Exec Command="xcopy \\myFileServer\Shortcut2LatestFiles\*.* c:\mytmp" ContinueOnError="true"/>
<HeatDirectory OutputFile="files.wxs" Directory="c:\mytmp" 
(... some more parameters ...) />
```

Unfortunately this workaround is not working, because xcopy does not resolve the symlink either.
Anyway I am not very happy about it and would prefer heat to directly use the shortcut. Is there a way to do so?

**EDIT:** the missing part actually were the quotes, like Alexey suggested - the xcopy part is working if I use

```
<Exec Command="xcopy &quot;c:\TestFolderSymlink&quot; &quot;c:\testtarget\&quot; /y" />
```

Funny enough they do not seem to be required on the command line.

**EDIT 2:** using the quotes, the direct use of the symlink in the heatdirectory task is possible too. However, be aware I am using a symlink (created by mklink, some info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)) here, not a shortcut (.lnk-File). Actually the Shortcut will not work this way.

Comment: What errors do you get? From `xcopy`, from `heat`?

Comment: xcopy is working if triggered from commandline, but says "file *.* not found" when invoked like above. I will try to create an example project as soon as I find the time to.

Comment: Try to add quotes `&quot;` around directories, maybe it helps…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments answered the question above but answering here so the question falls off the unanswered list for the `wix` tag.

When your path contains spaces or symlinks, be sure to quote the path. Quoting the path is usually a good idea in almost all cases. Note in XML you can use single quotes on the "outside" to use double quotes on the "inside" like:

```
<Exec Command='xcopy "c:\TestFolderSymlink" "c:\testtarget\" /y' />
```

That can often be more readable over the `&quot;` syntax.